# Visual studio 2013 Not full javascript IntelliSense when using a element object from the "getElementsByClassName" function

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense

When interacting with a html element via the "getElementById" function i get a full list of intellisense.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('host-canvas');
```

When using a dot on this object i can see all the proeprties such as "offsetwidth". 
However doing the same thing but using getElementsByClassName and then selecting the first object of the collection does not provide the same properties.

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('host-canvas')[0];
```

Now when i try to use intellisense i do not get options such as offsetwidth. Is there an explanation for this and anything i can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

(I originally wrote a comment saying this looks like a bug caused by a limitation of the VS JavaScript IntelliSense engine, but I think this is wrong, here's why:)

I think this is by-design, because multiple elements of different types can share the same class, consider this HTML:

```
 <img class="foo" />
 <p class="foo" />
```

This script would fail then:

```
 var fooElement = document.getElementsByClassName("foo")[0];
 fooElement.src = ; // <-- here
```

VS has no way of knowing `fooElement.src` would work because the `<p>` element might get returned instead, and `<p>` has no `src=""` attribute.

Comment: good point, however i am testing this out in a javascript file so the "getElementById" class wouldn't know either if it was a p , img or any other tag.